# Recursive menu, write all parents and childs

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, recurrence

I need a little help with recursive dropdown menu.

Here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 4
            [cat_name] => Plátna
            [cat_nodia] => Platna
            [cat_child] => 0
            [cat_desc] => 
            [cat_main] => 1
            [cat_order] => 4
            [parent] => 
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cat_id] => 16
                            [cat_name] => Ľanové
                            [cat_nodia] => Lanove
                            [cat_child] => 4
                            [cat_desc] => 
                            [cat_main] => 0
                            [cat_order] => 16
                            [parent] => Ľanové
                            [sub] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cat_id] => 17
                            [cat_name] => Bavlnené
                            [cat_nodia] => Bavlnene
                            [cat_child] => 4
                            [cat_desc] => 
                            [cat_main] => 0
                            [cat_order] => 17
                            [parent] => Bavlnené
                            [sub] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [cat_id] => 21
                                            [cat_name] => 10x10
                                            [cat_nodia] => 10x10
                                            [cat_child] => 17
                                            [cat_desc] => 
                                            [cat_main] => 0
                                            [cat_order] => 21
                                            [parent] => 10x10
                                            [sub] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [cat_id] => 22
                                            [cat_name] => 20x25
                                            [cat_nodia] => 20x25
                                            [cat_child] => 17
                                            [cat_desc] => 
                                            [cat_main] => 0
                                            [cat_order] => 22
                                            [parent] => 20x25
                                            [sub] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 5
            [cat_name] => Uhlík
            [cat_nodia] => Uhlik
            [cat_child] => 0
            [cat_desc] => 
            [cat_main] => 0
            [cat_order] => 5
            [parent] => 
            [sub] => 
        )
)
```

And I would like to make dropdown menu which would look like this:

```
Platna
Platna - Lanove
Platna - Bavlnene
Platna - Bavlnene - 10x10
Platna - Bavlnene - 20x25
Uhlik
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
   function show_menu($array)
    {
    //  print_r($array);
        foreach($array as $val)
        {
            if (is_array($val['sub']))
            {
                echo $val['cat_name'];
                $this->show_menu($val['sub']);
            }   else
            {
                echo $val['cat_name'];
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
```

Which gives me smh like this:

```
Plátna Ľanové
Bavlnené 10x10
20x25
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think this will help you. http://wizardinternetsolutions.com/articles/web-programming/single-query-dynamic-multi-level-menu

Comment: What i desired desired output ?

Comment: I mentioned it between codes

Comment: @Moylin - It build menu but I want to keep the parent and childs in the URL. It puts there only 1 parent and I want to have all parents and child there like: `parent/child/anotherChild`

Comment: That one is beyond the timeframe I have to throw at it. You'd either have to cycle back up the array id chain each time, pass something through to the recursive function to let it know it's depth and each prior menu name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   function show_menu($array, $name='')
    {
    //  print_r($array);
        foreach($array as $val)
        {
            echo $name . $val['cat_name'] . "<br>";
            if (is_array($val['sub']))
            {
                $this->show_menu($val['sub'], $name . $val['cat_name'] . ' - ');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Working but you are missing `"` at first echo. :) Thanks